# silverlight: showing/hiding user controls

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-2.0

My silverlight app takes the user through a sort of wizard-like process, so for each screen in the wizard I've created a seperate user control.  Then in my main user control (applications RootVisual) I just show/hide each user control when needed.  That means that every user control is instantiated at once,  is it possible to only have one use control loaded and visible at a time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jesse Liberty has some decent tutorials on multi-page Silverlight apps:

[Tutorial](http://silverlight.net/learn/tutorials/MultiPageApps_cs.aspx)
and
[Update](http://jesseliberty.com/2008/11/21/a-better-multi-page-solution/)